# Goes into limp mode while towing over 2k RPM

Tags: engine, lights, towing, isuzu, rodeo

I have a 2005 Isuzu Rodeo Denver, 3.0 automatic 190,000 miles on clock. Under heavy towing the engine management light comes on when over 2000 rpm, goes into idle mode. Drop the revs or down into neutral and it goes off, but accelerate up again and it comes on and goes in idle mode. Ten 2 cannot find a fault?? Changed both fuel filters and still the same issue. They, the isuzu garage, recon its the injector pump at some £3000 to have removed and rebuilt etc. Can anyone help me before I spend more on the pump than the the car is actually worth? In need of help desperately. Kind regards, Neil.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!